# SQL- use an attribute to group activities and use the group as parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| ActivityID | Time Used | Activity Type | Activity Category ID | Activity Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 30 | A | 1 | X |
| 765432 | 120 | B | 2 | Y |
| 876462 | 65 | C | 3 | Z |
| h52635 | 76 | D | 3 | Z |
| hsgs62 | 187 | E | 1 | X |

I would like to use the `Activity Category` as parameter (`@ActivityCategory`) to filter my report later, it means the filter should be X;Y;Z.

When I choose one Activity Category, the sum of "Time used" should appear.

My question is: how should I build the query, to be able to group the activities with the same Activity Category together and use the Category XYZ as a parameter?

Comment: A _table-valued parameter_  (TVP) would be a better choice than fiddling about with string parsing or dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (ActivityId INT, TimeUsed INT, ActivityCategory CHAR(1));
INSERT @table VALUES(123,20,'X'), (129,50,'Y'), (254,30,'Y'), (991,10,'Z');

-- Parameter
DECLARE @ActivityCategory VARCHAR(100) = 'X,Y';

SELECT      t.ActivityCategory, TimeUsed = SUM(t.TimeUsed)
FROM        @table AS t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@ActivityCategory,',') AS s -- You will need a string splitter funciton
WHERE       t.ActivityCategory = s.value
GROUP BY    t.ActivityCategory;
```

Returns:

```
ActivityCategory TimeUsed
---------------- -----------
X                20
Y                80
```

Comment: Aside: The mentioned "funciton" isn't _needed_. One can use Ye Olde `CharIndex( ';' + ActivityCategory + ';', ';' + @ActivityCategory + ';' ) > 0` to find matches. That should prevent an index seek. (The OP used semicolons, not commas, in their delimited values example.)

Answer (score 0):

Alan's answer is good, but I'd personally use a temp table and a join for performance reasons. The table being queried might be very large, in which case a join to a temp table would be more performant than CROSS APPLY.

The easiest way to pass multi-value parameters in and out of your query are comma-separated lists. Indeed if you are using Report Server / SSRS then that is how the "Multiple Value" box in the user interface will deliver the users' selections into a varchar parameter.

```
--Declare and set parameter
     DECLARE @ActivityCategories varchar(MAX)
         SET @ActivityCategories = 'X,Y,Z'

--Convert individual parameter values to a temp table
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ParamaterValues
CREATE TABLE #ParameterValues (ActivityCategory varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
 INSERT INTO #ParameterValues WITH(TABLOCK)
      SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ActivityCategories,',')
    GROUP BY value
    ORDER BY value

--Join on temp table to filter by paramater values
      SELECT ActivityID,
             TimeUsed,
             ActivityType,
             ActivityCategoryID,
             ActivityCategory
        FROM dbo.YourTable a
  INNER JOIN #ParameterValues b ON a.ActivityCategory = b.ActivityCategory
```